# Batch to compare last-modify from two files in different folders

Tags: file, batch-file

I want a batch file that will compare the `last-modify` date of two different files located in two different folders. If the local file is older than the server file, I want to overwrite the local file.

All I've found yet it a comparing the files with the `dir` command, which only works when both files are in the same folder (eg. `dir /b /OD file1.txt file2.txt`).

This is what I got actually, just need to add the comparison:

```bsh
set "source=\\server\myApp.otm"
set "target=%userprofile%\Application Data\myApp\"

copy /Y /B "%source%" "%target%"
start outlook.exe /altvba "%target%\myApp.otm"
```

As you can see, the batch file is here to start Outlook with the *VBA* *OTM* file in parameter. I don't want to copy the 10MB file from the server each time if it isn't needed, thus the need for a comparison of `last-modify` dates (`filesize` would be okay too I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `xcopy /d \\server\myapp.otm %userprofile%\...` it will copy the server file only if it is newer than the local file

Comment: Wow, this just works like a charm. I changed `copy /Y /B` for `xcopy /Y /D` and it's all right. Thank you very much, didn't think it would be that easy.